# React bug in my app. Trying to spread nested objects to update the data but I believe I am calling it wrong thus making two useState calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and have been stuck on this bug dealing with nested objects for a CV Creator app.

I am successfully passing up the new user data to the component I want to display it on but upon making the setState call I am duplicating the nested objects somehow. I have tried researching nested objects to find the root cause of this bug but have had no luck.

Here is the captured data being passed up to the component in this form.

```
    const enteredData = [
      {
        id: Math.random(),
        projectName: projectName,
        narrative: [
          {
            id: Math.random(),
            text: narrative,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

Here is the dummyData I am trying to update looks like this:

```
const dummyData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    projectName: "Labor Plan",
    narrative: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    projectName: "React Project",
    narrative: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Here is the useState call that is being duplicated.

```
const Projects = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummyData);
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const toggleHover = () => setHovered(!hovered);

  const saveDataHandler = (newData) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
      let idx = prevData.map((item, index) => {
        if (item.projectName === newData[0].projectName) {
          return index;
        }
      });
      console.log(idx);
      return [...newData, ...prevData];
    });
  };
```

So the above code is 1 of about 20 iterations I have tried thus far. The goal with the code is if the project names are equal I want to spread the new narrative data to the current list (this is the issue I am having a problem with --- currently not returning that in this iteration). If the project name does not exist then I can continue with the current return statement i have which is return [...newData, ...prevData];

[image]
Here is an image of the console double print.

**Desired Output**
[image]

So the desired output is when someone submits a project name that already exists it append the entered data to the existing data. This means keep the original Project information and just update the narrative key by spreading the new data on top of the existing data. If the project name does not exist I want just normally spread the list.

**EXTRA FULL COMPONENT CODE IF NEEDED**

Bug in This code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ProjectsEdit from "./ProjectsEdit";

const dummyData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    projectName: "Labor Plan",
    narrative: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    projectName: "React Project",
    narrative: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, possimus. Ex sunt harum, impedit sint facilis ipsam eligendi nam nobis unde officia recusandae eum placeat ab! Quo, tempora amet.",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const Projects = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummyData);
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const toggleHover = () => setHovered(!hovered);

  const saveDataHandler = (newData) => {
    setData((prevData) => {
      let idx = prevData.map((item, index) => {
        if (item.projectName === newData[0].projectName) {
          return index;
        }
      });
      console.log(idx);
      return [...newData, ...prevData];
    });
  };
  return (
    <div
      className={
        !hovered
          ? "contact-container main-content-subcontent editInactive"
          : "contact-container main-content-subcontent editActive"
      }
    >
      <h3 className="main-section-header" onMouseEnter={toggleHover}>
        Projects
      </h3>
      <div className="project-container">
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="sub-project-container">
                <h4 className="main-section-subHeader">{item.projectName}</h4>
                <ul className="project-list" key={item.id}>
                  {item.narrative.map((point) => {
                    return <li key={point.id}>{point.text}</li>;
                  })}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <ProjectsEdit saveData={saveDataHandler} toggleHover={toggleHover} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

The child component passing up the data

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ProjectsEdit = (props) => {
  const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState("");
  const [narrative, setNarrative] = useState("");

  const projectHandler = (e) => {
    setProjectName(e.target.value);
  };

  const narrativeHandler = (e) => {
    setNarrative(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const enteredData = [
      {
        id: Math.random(),
        projectName: projectName,
        narrative: [
          {
            id: Math.random(),
            text: narrative,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    props.saveData(enteredData);
    setNarrative("");
    setProjectName("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="edit-main">
      <form
        action=""
        onSubmit={submitHandler}
        className="form-container main-content-form"
      >
        <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">
          Project Name
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={projectHandler}
          className="form-input"
          value={projectName}
        />
        <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">
          Narrative
        </label>
        <textarea
          name=""
          id=""
          cols="30"
          rows="5"
          className="form-input"
          onChange={narrativeHandler}
          value={narrative}
        ></textarea>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="form-cancel form-button"
          onClick={props.toggleHover}
        >
          Close
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="form-submit form-button"
          onClick={props.toggleHover}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectsEdit;
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do with that `map()` call? Do you know what `Array.prototype.map()` does and how it uses the callback function?

Comment: it's not clear what your expected output is, or even really what your measured output is. but why are you using Array.map if you mean for that to return early when you could use Array.filter or Array.some?

Comment: Why is `enteredData` an array with only one element? Can there ever actually be more than one?

Comment: @BenG
All good points. I am currently using map right now because I have tried filter, for of, forEach and a couple other variations to try to get the desired output. When I used filter it would still insert double the data in the result. I just updated the post with a nimage of the desired result please see the bolded section called desired result.

Comment: @Phil no it cannot be more than one. Would this spread the enteredData to the previous data using this return [...prevData, enteredData] if enteredData was just an object?

And thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2):

### Not `map()`, use `findIndex` instead

You should not use `map()`, you can try this code:

```js
  const saveDataHandler = (newData) => {
    const target = [...data];
    const existedProjectIdx = target.findIndex(item => item.projectName === newData.projectName);

    // if not find, 'existedProjectIndex' will be -1 
    if (existedProjectIdx !== -1) {
       const { narrative } = target[existedProjectIdx];
       target[existedProjectIdx].narrative = [...narrative, ...newData.narrative]
    } else {
       target.push(newData)
    }
    
    setData(target)
  };
```

Comment: Minor detail, I think OP wants to prepend the new entries so `target.unshift(newData)` would be more appropriate

Comment: Either or would work! I am trying it out right now will advise!

Comment: @Phil Yep :), but this depends on the sort rule he wants

Comment: Another perhaps not so minor point but you can easily run into problems building on existing state outside of a [functional setter](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). I'd be inclined to move most of this into the `setData()` callback

Comment: @Wingsico I really appreciate it ! It does work and Phil I took your advice on not make entered Data a list of objects when it is only one!

Comment: @Phil Yes! It's a good practice, But most of the time, do not use `setData()` callback is also useful. If we are using it in an asynchronous condition, callback is a better choice

Comment: @wingsico that's not the problem. If you perform multiple updates before a re-render, only the last will apply.

Comment: @Phil if I am not mistaken by your last comment your advise would be to use the 
`
setData((prev) => {"updating data and returning new value"}
`
and put all the code inside. That is the only way I have learned this is actually my first react project I am working on :) I have tons more to learn about additional hooks and calls I could've done to avoid this issue. I did learn though avoid deeply nested objects, always make clones and brushed up on my map, filter and forEach methods lol I have been stuck on this for 8 hours before I asked.

Comment: @Phil I got it, I didn't notice the scene, Thank you for your correction

Comment: @pradetto5 _"avoid deeply nested objects"_... a good lesson to learn. That being said, [Redux Toolkit slices](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice) are a great way to work with larger state

Comment: @Phil Yes sir I will look into it learning Redux!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to merge the `narrative` arrays (via concatenation) for any same `projectName` entries and prepend any new entries.

The idea would be to find an entry by `projectName`. If you find it, alter the array at that position. Otherwise, prepend the new entry.

I also see absolutely no reason to wrap `enteredData` in an array.

```js
setData((prev) => {
  const foundIndex = prev.findIndex(
    ({ projectName }) => projectName === newData.projectName
  );
  if (foundIndex === -1) {
    return [newData, ...prev]; // not found, just prepend
  }

  // return a new array with a new, modified element at position `foundIndex`
  return [
    ...prev.slice(0, foundIndex),
    {
      ...prev[foundIndex],
      narrative: [...prev[foundIndex].narrative, ...newData.narrative],
    },
    ...prev.slice(foundIndex + 1),
  ];
});
```

As per [React guidelines](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)...

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

This is why it's best to compute the new value within the state setter function.